# Clicking noise when applying pressure on brakes

Tags: toyota

Let's say for example I'm cruising at 35MPH and decide to come to a gradual stop. I apply pressure to the brake pedal and a very faint "clicking" sound comes from the right rear wheel of my car. (I drive a 2005 Corolla S Automatic) However as I slow down, the louder and slower the clicking becomes.

It almost sounds like rotational clicking sounds that are faster and less loud at higher speeds, and get louder and slower paced as I slow down. But it's a constant clicking whenever I apply pressure to my brakes.

What could this be? I brought it to the dealership where I bought it (more than five times) and every time I went they claimed to have "fixed" it, but the noise comes back the next day.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking noise from applying brakes:

- Loose/worn brake pads
- Loose/broken pads anti-rattle springs
- Caliper cylinders retracting in an uneven way
- Caliper sliders not re-positioning correctly
- Brake disk bent (slightly bent you won't feel it in the pedal; really bent and you will feel the pedal vibrate)

All those can make the pads vibrate enough to make clicking/slapping sounds that, if not taken care, would increase with time.

Check them, replace as needed.

Comment: Alright great, thank you. Very much appreciated, I'll get these checked out.

Comment: ...and lets us know, so we grow our "collective intelligence" :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was my control arm bushings. Good way to confirm this is to push the car forward and backward really hard and see if the same clunk noise happens from this (it compresses and releases the bushings in the control arm)

Answer (score 0):

The clicking sound on my 2010 Camry was caused by the sway bar link, It sounded like a brake click. but by rocking the car back and forth while gripping the sway bar link with my hand the sound changed pitch, so look over all the suspension components and It might be there.